# How to pass array-values to Chart's properties i.e. xValue and yValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display chart on my webpage but i get the output as output image given below and when i pass array directly in Chart's xValue and yValue, it gives me expected reslut as given below but when i pass these values from my value, it gave the output image result as given below

```
public ActionResult GetChartImage(string Title, string[] xValue, string[] yValue)
{
    var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
        .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
        .AddSeries(
        chartType: "column",
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: xValue,
        yValues: yValue);

    return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Here is a View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
    <div>
        @{
            string[] names = { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" };
            string[] numbers = { "2", "7", "5", "3" };
        }
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetChartImage", new { Title = "Bar-Code", xValue = names, yValue = numbers })" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an output image

[image: Output Image]

But I want this

[image: Expected Image]

Comment: If you look at the html your generating your will see `...&xValue=System.String[]&yValue=System.String[]` You need to pass the values as `&xValue=Peter&xValue=Andrew...` etc

Comment: The [docs on AddSeries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart.addseries%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) say `...IEnumerable xValue,
 string xField,
 IEnumerable yValues,
 string yFields`

Comment: But why would you hard code values in the view. You may as well just assign those values in the `GetChartImage()` method

Comment: I could not get what you are saying, please can you point out the area where i should make changes in order to get correct output

Comment: It is just testing. but i will then pass the values from my database using entityframework to draw the chart

Comment: You cannot pass a collection using route values - the helper uses the`.ToString()` method of the values you provide, which in the case of `string[]` is `"System.String[]"` (not the values in the collection). But again, if the values are in the database, then get them from the database in the `GetChartImage()` method - having them in the view makes no sense.

Comment: **but i will then pass the values from my database using entityframework** . Yes. do that in your action method.,  inside `GetChartImage` method, instead of accepting arrays, you should accept a unique ids ( Ex : EmpoyeeId) using which you can derive data from your db and pass that to your chart.